# pdfbox: No glyph for U+2714 in font ZapfDingbats

Tags: java, pdfbox

If I use below code then I do not get the exception

```
pdPageContentStream.setFont(PDType1Font.ZAPF_DINGBATS, 10);
pdPageContentStream.beginText();
pdPageContentStream.newLineAtOffset(3, 4);           
pdPageContentStream.showText("\u2714");
pdPageContentStream.endText();
```

but if I use below code then I get the exception

```
PDType0Font font = null;

try(InputStream input = getClass().getClassLoader().
getResourceAsStream("ttf/zapfdingbatsRegular.ttf" )){
font = PDType0Font.load( pdDocument, input, false);
}

pdPageContentStream.setFont(font, 10);
pdPageContentStream.beginText();
pdPageContentStream.newLineAtOffset(3, 4);
pdPageContentStream.showText("\u2714");
pdPageContentStream.endText();
```

I need the second implementation in order my pdf to be validated as PDF/A.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does your `ttf/zapfdingbatsRegular.ttf` contain a glyph for `\u2714`?

Comment: I downloaded it from https://www.wfonts.com/font/zapfdingbats. I saw in the sample that it contains unicode 2714 (heavy check mark).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@mkl. Your comment helped me a lot. I found another ttf file and I realized that in the new ttf file the unicodes are different (0033 and 0037). So now I manage to solve the problem.

Comment: Great. Strictly speaking, though, the 33 and 37 are *not* unicode values for the heavy check mark, merely some character or glyph identifiers.